# Identify all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that are taken by $T$ to the same vector $T(a)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, linear-transformations

> If  = 
>   $$
>  a =
>  \begin{bmatrix}
>   a_1 \\
>   a_2
>  \end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^2\;\;\;\;T\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\3&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}$$
>   Identify all vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$
>   that are taken by $T$ to the same vector $T(a)$.

Here's the full question linked here: [screenshot of full problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMSfQ.png)

I figured out part A of the problem and found a basis for both $\ker(T)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(T)$.

$$
 \ker(T) = \operatorname{span}
 \left\langle\begin{bmatrix}
             2 \\
  1
 \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle $$and$$
$$

$$
 \operatorname{im}(T) = \operatorname{span}\left\langle
 \begin{bmatrix}
             1 \\
  3
 \end{bmatrix}\right\rangle
$$

Both being $1$-dimensional.

I need some help with part B of the question.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $v \in $Ker$(T)$ then

$T(a+v)=T(a)+0=T(a)$

and, if $T(x)=T(a)$ then

$T(x)-T(a)=T(x-a)=0$

Answer (score 0):

$T(a + k\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\end{bmatrix}) =T(a)+kT(\begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\end{bmatrix}) = T(a)$

Comment: is my solution for ker(T) wrong? I did RREF on the matrix and solutions i got were {x1 = 2t, x2 =t) perhaps, it should be x1 = -2t? please correct me if i'm wrong. thank u..

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix} 1&2\\3&6\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}4\\12\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: thank you! [-2 1] would result in [0 0] which is what we want. Gotcha, thanks for ur help